# Error SQL71501 unresolved reference to unnamed Assembly

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2022

I am trying to pull a dacpac from an existing database, importing it into a new SQL Project in VS2022. When I try to build the imported dacpac I get a bunch of errors like this one:

```
obj\Debug\MICROSOFT.BUILD.FRAMEWORK.generated.sql(8,1): Error:  SQL71501: Assembly: [Microsoft.Build.Framework] has an unresolved reference to unnamed Assembly.
```

Building the tables, functions, ... throws no error, only in those `*.generated.sql` files errors occur. All together there are 16 different Assemblies that throw a total of 49 `unresolved reference to unnamed Assembly` errors. I really have no clue how to tackle this one, since `unnamed Assembly` does not really give me a hint of what actually goes wrong.

I looked into some of these `*.generated.sql` files, but they all basically consist only of one big hexstring:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--     This code was generated by a tool.
--
--     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
--     the code is regenerated.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

CREATE ASSEMBLY [Microsoft.Build.Framework] AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
FROM 0x around 200 000 hexchars

WITH PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE

GO

ALTER ASSEMBLY [Microsoft.Build.Framework] WITH VISIBILITY = OFF;

GO
```

I also checked the Assemblies in the live database and looked at their dependencies to see, if there are some assemblies referenced, that are not included in my projects references, but I did not find any discrepancy.

`[Microsoft.Build.Framework]` as an example has the only dependency `System.Xaml` which is included in my projects references but still throws one instance of the `unresolved reference to unnamed Assembly` error.

How can I possibly fix this?